# Python 3 searching for a keyword more than once per line in a text file

Tags: python-3.x

Working on a simple script that searches a certain file for a keyword. Once it finds the keyword it counts how many times it was used and then records the line number of each time it found the keyword to a list. Then prints out the number of times it was found and in what lines. 
The program counts the keyword fine but after it is found once in a line it goes to the next line. It doesn't count more than one keyword. I know it does this because of the if statement: `if keyword in line:
                Number_Of_Key_Words = Number_Of_Key_Words + 1
                found_at.append(num)
                continue`

How do I get it to account for possible multiple keywords per line of the file?

Full Code:

```
def search():
Number_Of_Key_Words = 0
found_at = [];
keyword = input("Enter a key word to search for: ")
with open("WordList.txt") as file:
    for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if keyword in line:
            Number_Of_Key_Words = Number_Of_Key_Words + 1
            found_at.append(num)
            continue
    print(Number_Of_Key_Words)
    print("Found on lines: ", found_at)
search()
```

Example
word list

word word word

search for "word"
output : 1
found on lines [1]

Want:
output: 3
found on lines [1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `re` module `findall`, it will find all occurrence within the string.

Something like this (I have also suggested a few changes):

```
import re

keyword = input("...")
found_at = []
counter = 0  # Number_Of_Key_Words is not a good python name
# file is a PY2 built in, so I use 'f' instead
# also you should be explicit for the open mode, 'r' == read mode
with open("...", "r") as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        # re.findall() will return a list of all keyword occurrence
        # len() will then measure the occurrence effectively
        count = len(re.findall(keyword, line))
        if count > 0:  # ie. keyword in line at least once
            found_at.append(num)
            counter += count

    print(found_at)
    print(counter)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Tommy, like dreamzboy's answer using string `count()` is also a good idea, but you may benefit more from `re` module if you ever need to search keywords ignoring cases, or pattern matching etc., read the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). You should just explore and try more and learn from all.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use "str.count (keyword, start, end)"

Sample data "wordtext.txt":

```
red, blue, red, green.
blue, yellow, white.
green, orange.
red, blue, green, red, black, yellow, red.
```

Output:

```
>>> with open ('wordtext.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate (f, start = 1):
        found = line.count ('red')
        if found:
            print ('Line: %d  Red: %d' % (i, found))

            
Line: 1  Red: 2
Line: 4  Red: 3
>>>
```

Comment: I have to admit that the `re.findall()` answer was my first inclination, but this is certainly more elegant.

Comment: need to fix the enumerate start position or the line will be offset by 1. Also it's good idea to be explicit on file read mode

Comment: RE module is very powerful indeed but why import when you don't have to?  =)

Comment: @dreamzboy, you're right OP doesn't need `re` module in this occasion it's just one another way to solve a problem. Judging from his syntax & naming conversion he's clearly coming from the like of C-family language, which I believe will benefit from reading more different samples and learn to read from Python Docs and explore / adopt as much as possible

Comment: @Anzel - It's funny how you mentioned "C-family".  It's where I began as well.  I agreed that it's beneficial to have different approaches so thank you for contributing.

Comment: @dreamzboy, sure! And funnily enough I'm also from "C-family"... but it's like 20 years ago and I rarely write anything in C nowadays.